# Get ID and Mounted location of an USB

Tags: usb, udev

I need to find a way of retrieving the ID and Mounted Location for USB devices. 
I've found two commands that gives me what i want, but i haven't find how to associate them..

```
rsm@matrice:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:8187 Dell Computer Corp. DW375 Bluetooth Module
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 187c:0521 Alienware Corporation 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

rsm@matrice:~$ df -h
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                    898G  506G  346G  60% /
udev                       10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                     998M  744K  997M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/matrice-root  898G  506G  346G  60% /
tmpfs                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                     2.0G  752K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                 228M   20M  197M  10% /boot
/dev/sdc1                 7.7G  170M  7.5G   3% /media/New Volume
```

I've been trying to make a relation with commands like `dmesg` or `lsusb` but i haven't found how to do it! ( It would be great if it can be done without long logs because it will slow down my program)

---

EDIT: the answer by @don_crissti was great, and this can easily be done with `lsblk -lo`

Comment: (When i made the post, i tought that the ID of lsusb was the Serial Number, but it isn't, it is the IdVendor:IdProduct ). I need a way of getting the mounted location and the Serial Number of the USB devices. Getting the Serial Number it is easy, logs like `dmesg` print it, so i made a python script that retrieves it by using the "Filesystem id" (sdXX). This works pretty good except except with luks devices because `df -h` prints `/dev/mapper/..` instead of `/dev/sdXX`. I made a python script that seems to work for both cases, If anyone is interested i can email it :)

Comment: I really don't understand what is it that you're trying to do. Why would you even bother to parse `df` and `dmesg` output when `lsblk -lo name,tran,mountpoint,serial` would give you everything you need (e.g. devices serial number + mountpoints) ?

Comment: @don_crissti i was bothering me of doing all that work because i didn't know/find `lsblk` ! It is exactly what i needed thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, assuming your device sits are `/dev/sdc`

try an `ls -la /sys/dev/block/* | grep sdc`

That should be a good start.

However, I will say that `Bus 001 Device 011: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive` looks rather suspicious :)

Also, remember that `sdX` will get generated on the fly due to `udev`. So you might be hard pressed to make a **constant** script.

I suggest you look at writing udev rules. [Here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/9311/print) is a starter, it is out of date, but it'll help.

Comment: Thanks! i found how to do it. I use `df -h` which gives me the Mounted location and the file system "sdcX", then `ls -la /sys/dev/block/* | grep sdcX` and retrieve some sort of usb id.. like "3-1.2" that allows me to identify it in `dmesg | grep SerialNumber` :)

Comment: After more testing, i found that the previous method doesn't works when there are more than one usb plugged, because the "id" "3-1.2" is not really an id as you can see by doing `dmesg | grep SerialNumber:`. My best solution so far is to use `df -h` to get the filesystem and then search in the `dmseg` log as root ( the serial number is only displayed if you are root)...

Comment: @rsm As I said, you should look at writing a `udev` rule.

Comment: I'm actually having some problems with udev over Debian (probably newbie problems) so for the moment I'm using a python script that seems to do the work. But as soon as i can I'll try to make the udev rules, they seem good